# nginx proxy_pass receive content/status headers when http 4xx

Tags: nginx, http-headers, proxypass, 400

Was having some trouble as chronicled here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570550/play-2-2-1-simpleresult-4xx-response-body-possible-via-cors-xhr

But I didn't focus on nginx since the 200 OK happy path was working as expected. It was 400 level http errors that weren't working as expected. I wasn't receiving a body or able to get the status code inside browser XHR objects.

4xx http errors worked as expected via XHR (readyState=3 experienced) *only* when I was passing Access-Control-Allow-Origin from the application server, but I don't want this embedded in the code.

Is the only way to pass content and status headers for 4xx responses is to compile with [HeadersMoreNginxModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule)? Not ideal, but doable.

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

  def goodResponse = Action { implicit request =>
    // Ok("Hello world!")
    SimpleResult(
      header = ResponseHeader(200, Map(CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/json")),
      body = Enumerator("Hello world!".getBytes())
    )
  }

  def badResponse = Action { implicit request =>
    // BadRequest(
    //   """{"error":"bad request"}"""
    // )
    SimpleResult(
      header = ResponseHeader(
        400, 
        Map(
          CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/json",
          ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN -> "*"     // FIXME: move to nginx?
        )
      ),
      body = Enumerator("""{"error":"bad request"}""".getBytes())
    )
  }

}
```

My nginx.conf uses a proxy_pass to the play server on port 9000:

```
http {

  # ...snipped...

  upstream api {
    server localhost:9000;
  }

  server {
    #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    ssl_certificate      /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/api.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from https://api/
    server_name api;

    location / {
      # See http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html
      # Modified to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin"
      include nginx_cors.conf;

      proxy_pass http://api;

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your entire nginx configuration and make sure you didn't set `proxy_intercept_errors on;` somewhere. This setting should be `off` in your scenario.

Comment: The rest of nginx config is basically stock except for some logging, I did not add proxy_intercept_errors anywhere.